# Rails : Where Can I find render API Documentation for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a specific case of a general problem I sometimes encounter in rails.

I'm looking at some code in a controller:

```
def index
  render: json: rec, 
          serializer: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer,
          each_serializer: RecSerializer,
          meta: {status: rec_status}
end
```

In this case, the controller inherits from ActionController::API.

I'd like to find the api documentation for render that includes the parameters used in the above render call.

When I goto https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/API.html I don't see much about render.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ApiRendering.html does not seem to show anything useful to me.

At least here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ApiRendering.html the json argument shows up.

So, am I missing something?  Using the API documentation, how would I ever know that serializer:, each_serializer, and meta are valid arguments?  How would I know what they do?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html has a big section on render.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some documentation here on this github link that documents the parameters I asked about:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable#how-options-are-parsed